# How to register a function that is later called?

Tags: c#, interface, delegates, task-parallel-library, function-prototypes

I run a console application and declared and instantiated an object of type `Foo`. Besides the `Main()` method I want to specify an additional method (lets call it `ProcessMessages()`) and have it perform some work. The main job of `Foo` is to accept messages that are sent to a tcp socket and processed. As part of the process I need to specify a function `func<T>` to which such messages are passed. `ProcessMessages()` (outside of Foo) is supposed to be such function. How can I register this function with foo without having to pass reference to its containing class?

Foo contains a TPL data flow bock which requires a `func<T>` which operates on the queued items in the block. But the function is not contained within Foo but in the class that instantiated an object of type Foo. I am looking for the fastest way of later on calling this method even if I have to write more elaborate code. Ultimately I want to hide the underlying tpl data flow block within Foo and only want to call a function in Foo that sets up a tpl data flow block and registers with it a method that is located outside of Foo to which items can be passed later on. What is the best way to get this done? The registration part is the one which puzzles me.

EDIT: Here is some code that describes maybe better what I try to achieve:

a) In Main() I have the following method which is getting called from within a different class:

```
public void OnControlMessage(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Comp1 received Control Message");
    }
```

I register this Method in the following way:

```
List<ZeroMqMessaging.CallBackMethod> registeredMethods = new List<ZeroMqMessaging.CallBackMethod>(){ 
            new ZeroMqMessaging.CallBackMethod(MessageType.ControlMessage, OnControlMessage) };
```

b) The ActionBlock that invokes the callback looks as follows:

```
ActionBlock<Tuple<int, byte[]>> newActionBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<int, byte[]>>(x => callback.eventHandler(this, new MyEventArg(callback.messageType, x.Item2)));
```

OnControlMessage gets called correctly, however, I need to pass specific messages to OnControlMessage as part of EventArgs. I created a class MyEventArg that derives from EventArg but I still am not able to access members of MyEventArg in OnControlMessage.

Preferably I like to have OnControlMessage(ControlMessage message){...} in order to not to have to cast. How can I register this OnControlMessage so that I can call back this method with arguments of my choosing? I have potentially many different such callback methods so requirement is to stick to a 1-line short way to register as I currently do in a) when I create CallBackMethod objects. I hope this is somewhat clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but perhaps you want to define an [Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(v=VS.100).aspx) for your object?

Comment: It's hard to understand what do you want to get, so can you post some code that have you tried? Thank you.

Comment: Will search for function prototype thanks.

Comment: I will add some code samples soon,sorry for being so unclear

Comment: @AlexW, I searched for function prototypes and got to extension methods. If you mean EM then I think I must have been incredibly unclear in my question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Freddy **Function Prototype**: a declaration of a function that omits the function body but does specify the function's return type, name, arity and argument types. While a function definition specifies what a function does, a function prototype can be thought of as specifying its interface.

Comment: This looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951840/method-to-register-method-to-be-called-when-event-is-raised

Comment: @Alex, this was actually a lot easier than I thought. Thanks for the link which helped to make it a lot clearer

Comment: @AlexW, I went through EventHandlers but seem to now run into problems with custom EventArgs. Could you please point me to how to do this with Func<>? I went to the link you provided but it also only deals with the system (object sender, EventArgs args) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to create a delegate:

```
public delegate void MyMessageHandler(string message);
```

You can then use it like this:

```
public void Work(MyMessageHandler callback)
{
    string message = "";
    ....
    callback(message);
}
```

You then call it like this:

```
public Main()
{
    Work(ProcessMessages);
}
public void ProcessMessages(string message)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Along those lines. If I store "callback in your "use section" I assume that I can invoke callback as often as I want and pass strings to it and in essence the delegate will ensure that ProcessMessages is called back each time? I want to "register" ProcessMessage in Main() only once.

Comment: I'd recommend just using Func and Action rather than defining custom delegates

Comment: @JamesManning, of course but the question is how to access the Func that is not specified within the class that implements the action blocks but within the super class

Comment: Just invoke it like you would the delegate

Comment: @James, this was actually a lot easier than it seemed. Not that I have a CS background but I should definitely get more comfortable with Delegates/Events 101.

Comment: @Cashperah, thanks for the code, the Work method confused me initially as my original question was about registering a function rather than performing the callback but it nonetheless helped, thanks.

Comment: @Casperah, how would I register this delegate so that the callback can occur in a class different from where Main() and ProcessMessages(...) lie?

Comment: James I followed your advice and used Action<T> which worked perfectly. Thanks a lot